# Why when using TPH inheritance are default values ignored?

Tags: entity-framework-4

```
CREATE TABLE Lodging
(
     LodgingID int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
     LodgingName nvarchar(100),
     Resort bit NOT NULL,
     ResortChainOwner nvarchar(100) NOT NULL,
         ...
)
```

`Lodging` DB table maps to `Lodging` entity. I've then implemented a TPH inheritance:

• With `Lodging` entity being the base

• I've created a new entity `Resort`, which derives from `Lodging`.

• I moved resort-specific property `ResortChainOwner` to the `Resort` entity type and also set ( in SSDL ) `ResortChainOwner's` Default Value to `"notApplicable"`

• Lodging table's `Resort` column  is a discriminatory column. If `Resort` column contains `0`, then records is materialized into `Lodging` entity and if column contains `1`, then record is materialized into `Resort` entity

When in the following code `SaveChanges` is called, EF should supply (to Insert command) a default value for `ResortChainOwner` field, but instead it supplies a `Null`

```
        var lodging = new Lodging();
        ...
        context.Lodgings.AddObject(lodging);
        context.SaveChanges();
```

So how do I on inserts force EF to supply a default value for ResortChainOwner column?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You've defined a default value for the Resort class, but you've instantiated a the super class "Lodging". So instead use:

```
var lodging = new Resort();
```

The base class "Lodging" doesn't even have that property anymore if I understand you well.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your `Lodging` entity to abstract and create a second entity which derives from `Lodging`. I have a feeling TPH works only on classes actually inheriting from the class containing the discriminator field.